# Attempting to set a new location for Log File for SNMP Trap Daemon in Ubuntu 20.04.1 - What is the Syntax in the .CONF file to do so?

Tags: 20.04, snmp

I am attempting to set up an SNMP Trap receiver with an Ubuntu Linux VM.  This VM is being configured to recieve SNMP traps and then I would like to have them logged to a log file on an NFS mount, so that I can back up these logs on my RAID array.

When I manually start snmptrapd with the -tLf option, it works great:

```
snmptrapd -tLf /mnt/log/snmptest.log
```

However, I cannot find any documentation on how to do this in the snmptrapd.conf file; how I can edit that to force logging to a specific location.  I've searched through multiple Bing and Google searches, as well as read the man pages for snmptrapd and snmptrapd.conf.  No dice.

Any suggestions on how to enable this through the snmptrapd.conf?  I could, I suppose, do this by editing the .service file to force the location, but I'd prefer something in the .conf file instead.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "logOption string     specifies  where  notifications  should  be  logged  - to standard output, standard error, **a specified file** or via syslog"